# cx_freeze : compiled tkinter app is not lauching

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

It is the first time I'm using cx_freeze and I really need help on this, I've been looking everywhere but i can't find an answer.

I don't have any error during the compiling process, but the executable file just doesn't do anything. Could someone please explain me why?

Here is my project structure:

Application

- setup.py
- application.py (Tkinter app that import 2 functions from cell.py)
- logo.jpg
- favicon.ico
- responsible.xls
- modules:

  - cell.py (all the work is done in this file)

I don't know where to include the file cell.py in setup, for now it's in a file Modules. And i'm not sure if Tkinter should be include or exclude.

Here is the file setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


executables = [
        Executable("application.py")
]

buildOptions = dict(
        compressed = True,
        includes = ["sys","re","PIL","ttk","xlrd","xlutils","datetime","string","Tkinter"],
        include_files = ["responsible.xls","favicon.ico","logo.jpg"],
        excludes = []
        path = sys.path + ["modules"]
)

setup(
    name = "test",
    version = "1.1.1.0",
    description = "test",
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
 )
```

Comment: Try launching it from a command prompt - there may be an error that you don't see when double clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

You add the directories you want to include with the include_files option.
So this part of your code should be like this:

```
buildOptions = dict(
        compressed = True,
        includes = ["sys","re","PIL","ttk","xlrd","xlutils","datetime","string","Tkinter"],
        include_files = ["responsible.xls","favicon.ico","logo.jpg", "modules"],
        excludes = []
        path = sys.path + ["modules"]
)
```